# Unreachable code in Python Turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I started to program a few days ago and today I've tried to do the game 'Pong' using Python.

But since I am a beginner I can't find what is wrong with the code.

When I try to create a `turtle.Turtle`, the Pycharm says the code is unreachable.

```
    # Game Pong

import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Quarentena 21/03")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.tracer(0)

# Main Game Loop
while True:
    wn.update()

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.color('green')
paddle_a.penup()
```

Comment: all the `paddle_a` code is unreachable, once your program gets to the `while True` it'll never go past that because it'll always be looping there

Comment: How would you ever get out of the `while` loop to get to the code below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the code is unreachable. Unless you put something to break the loop, 'while True' continues forever because the default condition is always `True` unless you set it to false. So you can't reach the code below the loop. Happy programming! :)